# How to fix TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a problem with my program that is supposed to sort even and odd numbers.

The code:

```
everything = []
print("Type all your numbers and then type stop")
while True:
    nove = input()
    if nove == "stop":  
        break
    else:
        everything.append(nove)
numbers = [s for s in everything if s.isdigit()]
print("All numbers:")
for number in numbers:
    print(number)

print("Odd numbers:")
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 1:
        print(number)
    else:
        continue
print("Even numbers:")
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number)
    else:
        continue
```

**It returns this:**

```
*Type all your numbers and then type stop
>68
>11
>stop  All numbers: 68 11 Odd numbers: Traceback (most recent call last):    File "tridicka.py", line 16, in <module>
     if number % 2 == 1: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
     ------------------ (program exited with code: 1)*
```

Comment: You should convert the numbers from string to int, e.g. `numbers = [int(s) for s in everything if s.isdigit()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs are string, you need to parse thel as `int`

```
numbers = [int(s) for s in everything if s.isdigit()]
```

---

Also this part is useless, as there is no other cde to run after

```
else:
    continue
```

Just do

```
print("Odd numbers:")
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 1:
        print(number)

print("Even numbers:")
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number)
```

Comment: @LosSkillos you can mark an answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answered you question.